# How to differentiate $f(x) = (9-xe^x)/(x+e^x) $

Tags: calculus

The correct result should be $-(e^{2x}+(x^2+9)e^x+9)/(x+e^x)^2$
but I cannot understand how to get to that conclusion.

I have tried to solve it myself using the quotient rule, but the result is different:
$ e^x(−x^2+x−9)−9)/(x+e^x)^2 $

Comment: yes, but the result is different, this is the result: $(e^x(-x^2+x-9)-9)/(x+e^x)^2$

Comment: Apply the quotient rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule

Comment: You made an arithmetic error. Go back and do it again carefully. You can write down your solution for us to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done by quotient rule. Hope it is not a homework problem! Denominator comes directly from quotient rule.

$$Numerator = (9-xe^x)'(x+e^x)-(9-xe^x)(x+e^x)'$$ where prime denotes differentiation

Hence

$$Numerator=(-e^x-xe^x)(x+e^x)-(9-xe^x)(1+e^x)$$
$$=(-e^{2x}-xe^x-x^2e^x-xe^{2x})-(9+9e^x-xe^x-xe^{2x})$$
$$=-(e^{2x}+x^2e^x+9e^x+9)$$